# How to use ng-class in angularjs table?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-class

I have 3 css class namely

```
.green{
  background-color:green
}

.yellow{
  background-color:yellow
}

.red{
  background-color:red
}
```

And I have a table

which looks like this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr class="bg-primary">
            <th>Task Name</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th ng-hide="true">autoid</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="d in dataintbl">
            <td>{{d.taskname}}</td>
            <td>{{d.taskstartdate}}</td>
            <td>{{d.taskenddate}}</td>
            <td>{{d.taskpriority}}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" ng-click="updateuser()" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></a>
                <a href="#" ng-click="deleteuser()" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>
            </td>
            <td ng-hide="true">{{d.taskmid}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

now in my `<td>{{d.taskpriority}}</td>`I have data like

> low medium high

now I want to use ng-class in my td and apply css class as per data

if I have (low) in my td, green css class should be apply and so on

what I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8309832/6804648](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8309832/6804648) see this for batter understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
<td ng-class="{'green': (d.taskpriority == 'low'), 'yellow': (d.taskpriority == 'medium'), 'red': (d.taskpriority == 'high')}">{{d.taskpriority}}</td>
```

`ng-class` accepts a map of class names to boolean values. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)