# How to add styles based on condition

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to add css to my div based on my input checkbox

```
<div class="pvreveal"  [style]="ShowHideSection ? 'overflow:scroll;height:483px':''"  >
 <input id="isDelivery" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="ShowHideSection " />
</div
```

How to achieve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Style Based On Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663839/angular-style-based-on-condition) - i.e. `<span ng-style="{background-color:(CONDITIONS FOR GREEN)?'green':'red'">Text</span>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `[ngClass]`. I am not a big fan of inline styles

//CSS

```
.myClass{overflow:scroll;height:483px}
```

//Component

```
export class MyComponent {

    public ShowHideSection : boolean = true;
}
```

//HTML

```
<div class="pvreveal"  [ngClass]="{'myClass' : ShowHideSection}"  >
 <input id="isDelivery" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="ShowHideSection " />
</div>
```